# Need to recover webpage cache after reloading it

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I had a webpage open in Chrome, was reading a forum thread. I reloaded the page but found that the thread had been deleted. 
Did I wipe the cached page when I reloaded it? Or could there be some way to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be in luck, but then again like you said you may have already over wrote it.

You can check by typing the following into your address bar: about:cache

This will then produce a page with all cached websites, just ctrl+f to find the site.